# Java 8+ streams - from Map<String, Object> that contains other maps to count of total objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm here to ask a question related to streams.
I have a list of `class C`  in a structure like that:

```
list<C> listC 

class C {
  Map<String, ClassB>
}
classB {
  Map<String, ClassA>
}
classA {
 int value;
}

int sumOfValues = ?
```

My aim is to understand the best way possible to have the sum of all the values, iterating maps with streams.

I know how to do it with a normal loop or a forEach structure, but I'm not totally sure on how to best perform this operation through streams.

I tried something like :

```
listC.stream().map(C::getMap).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
                    .map(m -> m.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

But I don't think is the right path...

Can someone help me understanding the best way to iterate list of Map structures?
Thanks a lot

Comment: There’s no sense in inserting `.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()` in the middle of a Stream. Remove it and the code still does the same, except for not wasting resources to fill an ephemeral list. The second `.collect(Collectors.toList())` also leads to nowhere. You do not want a list but summing an int, so why are so obsessed with collecting into a list?

Comment: Hi @Holger, you are totally right. I am aware that this was not the right direction and thats why I asked here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me you are looking for [Stream.flatMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element.

> The flatMap() operation has the effect of applying a one-to-many transformation to the elements of the stream, and then flattening the resulting elements into a new stream.

Example:

```
int sum = list.stream()
            .flatMap(c -> c.getMap().values().stream()) //map to stream of B's
            .flatMap(b -> b.getMap().values().stream()) //map to stream of A's
            .mapToInt(A::getValue) //map to IntStream of the values
            .sum();
```

Comment: "*A Stream is not a collection, you can't iterate it*" I don't agree with this. It's still iteration. It's just declarative rather than imperative. You can even create a Stream with a method *called* iterate.

Comment: @Michael Even then it's not a collection and you are not iterating it. The docs for `Stream.iterate()` state - `Returns a ... Stream produced by iterative application of the given next function to an initial element ...`. The next function is applied iteratively on the previous element to **generate** the next one.

Comment: If you want get into semantics, a Collection is not the only thing you can iterate. An Iterable is. In any case, you *are* iterating the elements when you use a stream. You are just not necessarily iterating *all* of the elements, depending on the terminal operation. What is your definition of "iterate"? Because it seems non-standard.

Comment: But a Stream is not an Iterable. I am not trying to get into semantics war, but probably can't express my thought correctly. What i was trying to say is this - `No storage. A stream is not a data structure that stores elements; instead, it conveys elements from a source such as a data structure, an array, a generator function, or an I/O channel, through a pipeline of computational operations.` Quoted from the package summary. In my understanding that's not exactly an iteration, at least not in the same way an Iterable is iterated. Might be wrong though.

Comment: It's certainly not something which stores elements, but then neither is an Iterator (at least for most practical implementations, it's a pointer). Would you say "An Iterator is not a collection, you can't iterate it"? I'd say "[conveyance] through a pipeline of computational operations" is basically what iteration is.

Comment: "*I am not trying to get into semantics war*" No, me neither. Mainly what I'm trying to express is that I think your first sentence is bad advice, at least for how I personally think of streams. I do think of them as a form of iteration. The main difference compared with a traditional for-loop, as far as I'm concerned, is how you express how the iteration will happen: declaratively vs imperatively.

Answer (score 2):

You can try it like this:

```
static class ClassC {
  Map<String, ClassB> content;
}
static class ClassB {
  Map<String, ClassA> content;
}
static class ClassA {
 int value;
}


public static void main (String[] args){

    List<ClassC> listC = null; // needs to be initialized properly

    int sumOfValues = listC.stream().flatMap(c -> c.content.values().stream()).flatMap(b -> b.content.values().stream()).mapToInt(a -> a.value).sum();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, we can use flatMap and solve this in a easy way.

```
int sumOfValues = listC.stream() // Stream<C>
            .flatMap(c -> c.map.values().stream()) // Stream<B>
            .flatMap(b -> b.map.values().stream()) // Stream<A>
            .mapToInt(a -> a.value) // stream of map to IntStream 
            .sum();
```

The other way to write the last two step which seems more readable for a beginner

```
            listC.stream()
            .flatMap(c1 -> c1.map.values().stream())
            .flatMap(b1 -> b1.map.values().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.summingInt(a -> a.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
Integer result = C_list.stream()
   .flatMap(s -> s.getC_map().values().stream()) 
   .flatMap(s -> s.getB_map().values().stream())
   .map(A -> A.getValue())
   .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```